# Xamarin iOS project need suggestion

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing a survey app using Xamarin and Mvvmcross. Can some one help with suggesting a way to build a View to display questionnaire. These questionnaire will be supplying from my View Model as a List of question with Question Text, Answer options. Based on a flag I need to prompt the questionnaire with input type as drop down or Text boxes. Number of questions can be vary.

In Android I achieved it using MvxGridView and Layout templates. But not sure how to do it in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could look up `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` and `UITextFields` and `UIPickerView`

Answer (score -1):

Wellcome to Xamarin, about your question you can just take look the code I wrote for others, it's a tableview include custom cell to display images, you can just modify the MyTableCell.cs class to display anything you want.

[Custom cell tableview(Xamarin.iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876155/xamarin-ios-vertically-scroll-through-images/38877572#38877572)

If you still need some help, just leave it here, I will check latter.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look. seems like what I am looking for

Comment: I use MvxTableViewController to list the questions. as per my use case after I select a question it will load another table to select the answer options. Selecting an option will trigger NavigationController.PopViewController( true) to go back to questions. Now my problem is Question table is not refreshing with the updated response to show them. Any idea. I use below code
 
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
....
 InvokeOnMainThread(delegate
            {

               
                TableView.ReloadData();
            });

Comment: I just found a solution to update the table values https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28460/uitableview-update-the-cells-not-a-full-reload